# Filter dataframes where two columns equal to same value

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way or writing

```
filter(dataDF, column1 == 'myvalue' & column2 == 'myvalue')
```

without having to write out `myvalue` twice?

Comment: here's how: `filter(dataDF, column1 == 'myvalue' & column2 == column1)` (I guess that's not what you're looking for)

Comment: hmm, better than what I had. Reasons I want to do it is 1. Such that if I need to go and edit what 'myvalue' at a later date I only need to change it in once place and 2. To make code as efficient and short as possible. Your solution solves number 1. but not number 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::filter_at`

```
filter_at(dataDF, c("column1", "column2"), all_vars(. == 'myvalue'))
```

Answer (score 2):

By your comment,

> hmm, better than what I had. Reasons I want to do it is 1. Such that if I need to go and edit what 'myvalue' at a later date I only need to change it in once place and 2. To make code as efficient and short as possible. Your solution solves number 1. but not number 2

You can put the 'myValue' in a variable and use it . That way you only have to update/change it at one place.

```
valueToCheck='myvalue'
filter(dataDF, column1 == valueToCheck & column2 == valueToCheck)
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a clunky base-R solution

```
df[do.call(`&`, lapply(df[, c('column1', 'column2')], `==`, myvalue)), ]
```